# Get Image to break between pages with react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, image, pdf, react-pdf

I am looking for a method that allows Images to be broken and "wrap" between pages using the react-pdf library.

In other words, if the image doesn't fit on the remainder of the page, I'm looking for a way for the top portion of the image to stay on the first page, and the remainder of the image to be split and shown on the next page.

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same problem... It seems that it's not currently supported as there's no wrap prop

https://react-pdf.org/components#image

> Unbreakable components are indivisible, therefore if there isn't
> enough space for them they just get rendered in the following page. In
> this group by default we only find Image.

https://react-pdf.org/advanced#page-wrapping